# How to validate ant design formitems without using getFieldDecorator in reactjs?

Tags: reactjs, validation, antd

In reactjs i am using ant design form. In that form i dont want default validation using getfielddecorator. I want to validate fields with my own validation.How it validate?
For example

```
 <Form onSubmit={this.handlesubmit.bind(this)}>                                                                                                        <FormItem>                                                       
    <input/>                                              
</FormItem>
 <FormItem >                                                       
  <input/>                                                                                                                      
 </FormItem>                                                
<ButtonAnt className="btng" type="primary" htmlType="submit">Save</ButtonAnt>                                                   
 </Form>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to the [docs](http://2x.ant.design/components/form/#components-form-demo-validate-static),

> We provide properties like `validateStatus` `help` `hasFeedback` to
>   customize your own validate status and message, without using
>   `Form.create` and `getFieldDecorator`.

Also, it seems there is a `validator` prop ([amongst others](http://2x.ant.design/components/form/#Validation-Rules)) that you can use to write your own validator function.

Comment: yeah i implemented like that. Thank u

Comment: Can you please add an example?

Answer (score 2):

I do it like this

```
<Form.Item
  help={HasError && meta.error}
  validateStatus={HasError ? "error" : "validating"}
>
  <Input {...input} {...props} className={classes.Input}></Input>
</Form.Item>
```